# Codeigniter How to in Array use where OR, AND clause

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am looking for query in Codeigniter works like where OR, AND both works.

This is working Perfect!

```
$srcArr2['emp_id']=8;
$srcArr2['status']='2';
$this->db->where($srcArr2);
$query = $this->db->get('tickets');
$res = $query->result_array(); // as array
print_r ($res);
```

query is:

Need to add  OR  in where with $srcArr1['ass_id']=12;
I try but not working.

```
$srcArr1['ass_id']=12;
$srcArr2['emp_id']=8;
$srcArr2['status']='2';
$this->db->where($srcArr2);
$this->db->where_in($srcArr1);
$query = $this->db->get('tickets');
$res = $query->result_array(); // as array
print_r ($res);
```

Thank You, in Advance for help

Answer (score 1):

You can use or_where_in to achieve the same,

```
$this->db->or_where_in($srcArr1);
```

Official [doc](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->where($srcArr2);
$this->db->or_where($srcArr1);
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data[enter link description here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)